# Android Own Array Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

Sorry for my English. I have my own `ArrayAdapter` for list activity . My problem: when I take datas to web service , datas are added `ArrayList`. Everything is normal up here. Nexus and Android OS 4.0 is listing the data, but other phone and 2.3.3 do not list the data. Everything is normal and I have not received any error.

I have no idea what's problem. Program listing data with Nexus(OS 4.0), but not listing in 2.3.3.

- My main activity class is extend ListActivity

  - public static ArrayList freqzo; static MobileArrayAdapter freqz;
  - freqzo=new ArrayList(); freqz=new MobileArrayAdapter(this,freqzo);
  - this.setListAdapter(freqz); ListView lv = getListView();
  - lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true); //And my filling arraylist part: if (store
  - instanceof Vector) { Object[] arr = ((Vector) store).toArray(); for
  - (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { freqzo.add((String) arr[i].toString()); }

My Mobile Adapter class:

```
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.listlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);

        String s = values.get(position);
        Log.d("Liste", "Liste " + values.get(position));
        if (s != null && !s.equals("")) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }

        // Change icon based on name
        // String s = values[position];

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe after filling your list you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Answer (score 0):

That piece is bad:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, parent, false);
```

first, you don't use the view that was created for you by adapter, but always create a new one. Java machine will clean excessive objects, but it takes heaps of time. Second, ArrayAdapter can do all the work. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532548/715269)